# LaTeX3: tokens for curly braces

Tags: expl3, latex3, braces

I use a clist of delimiters to define functions that enclose text within the said delimiters.

Here is a MWE:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_delim_clist
\clist_put_right:Nn \l_delim_clist {
  {paren, (, )},
  {curly, \{, \}},
  {brac, [, ]}
}

\clist_new:N \l_delim_specs
\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_delim_clist {
  \clist_clear:N \l_delim_specs
  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_delim_specs {#1}
  \clist_pop:NN \l_delim_specs \l_delim_name
  \clist_pop:NN \l_delim_specs \l_delim_start
  \clist_pop:NN \l_delim_specs \l_delim_end

  \cs_new_nopar:cpx {delim_ \l_delim_name :n} ##1 {\l_delim_start ##1 \l_delim_end}
}

\show\delim_paren:n
\show\delim_brac:n

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now, on compilation, TeX runs out of stack space.  This seems to be because of the curly part.  In particular, removing line 6:

```
  {curly, \{, \}},
```

leads to correct compilation with the expected result.    That is, `\show\delim_paren:n` does yield:

```
> \delim_paren:n=macro:
#1->(#1)
```

I would like `\delim_curly:n` to be the macro `#1->\{#1\}` which may be used in math mode.  Could someone shed some light on the reason TeX runs into an infinite loop and how I may fix the above code?  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that `\{` and `\}` (with their current definition) are not “fully expandable” and so they don't survive `\edef` (which you are using with `\cs_new_nopar:cpx`

Comment: if you only want math you could use `\lbrace` and `\rbrace` instead of \{ \}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `\{` and `\}` inside an `x` expansion argument, unless you take precautions not to expand them. The same problem doesn't apply with the other delimiters because they're character tokens.

You can exploit the fact that `\clist_item:nn` returns the item with `\exp_not:n` around it.

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_arakonam_delim_clist
\clist_set:Nn \l_arakonam_delim_clist
 {
  {paren, (, )},
  {curly, \{, \}},
  {brac, [, ]}
 }

\clist_map_inline:Nn \l_arakonam_delim_clist
 {
  \cs_new_nopar:cpx {delim_ \clist_item:nn {#1} {1} :n} ##1
   {
    \clist_item:nn {#1} {2}
    ##1
    \clist_item:nn {#1} {3}
   }
 }

\cs_show:N \delim_paren:n
\cs_show:N \delim_brac:n
\cs_show:N \delim_curly:n

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Here's the output on the terminal:

```
> \delim_paren:n=macro:
#1->(#1).
<recently read> }

l.24 \cs_show:N \delim_paren:n

? 
> \delim_brac:n=macro:
#1->[#1].
<recently read> }

l.25 \cs_show:N \delim_brac:n

? 
> \delim_curly:n=macro:
#1->\{#1\}.
<recently read> }

l.26 \cs_show:N \delim_curly:n

?
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer was to the point (and very quick too).  \clist_item:nn seems like a recent addition and is not available in my expl3 package.  I did get it working by saying:  `{curly, {\exp_not:n {\{}}, {\exp_not:n {\}}}},`

Comment: @arakonam It's much better to have a very up-to-date `expl3` bundle. You can also use your code, but with `\exp_not:V \l_delim_start` and `\exp_not:V \l_delim_end`. However, note that you're using wrong variable names and don't declare them.

Comment: I'm writing these macros towards easy semantics for writing papers in my area of research.  I am aiming towards making the package as inter-operable with an eye towards submitting to journals / colloborating with who might not have but a standard texlive distribution.  Thus, while I could pull an svn version, my co-authors / journals might not like to do it; this would lead to having to worry about bundling the package but that's a separate question altogether.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the naming convention suggests \l_delim_start_tl I suppose and that I should define them.  I will remember that.

Comment: @arakonam The feature `clist_item:nn` has been in `expl3` (as an 'experimental addition') for some time. Trying to use too old an `expl3` version is fraught with issues: we are still developing the language and its not realistic to hope to use arbitrary older versions .

Comment: @JosephWright: I agree with you.  My priority is to make it compatible with journals I / my collaborators publish our work in and it is not reasonable to expect them to update to the latest and the greatest.  Thanks to you and the rest of the LaTex3 team for the well-designed l3kernel.  Keep up the good work!